# Pointfree generalization of uniform spaces?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Topological spaces generalize as frames and locales.

But are there a pointfree generalization of uniform spaces?

Comment: Yes: [uniform locales](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/uniform+locale). Isbell discusses them in his 1972 paper, though I'm not sure if the definition on nLab is the same as his.